# Create session on android and destroy the session in specific time

Tags: android, session, time

I have tried all the similar questions in stackoverflow, but still doesn't give me the right answer (like what i looking for).

I try to create a session in a day. The session will destroy in specific time

```
private void notifyPopUpWhen24Hours(){
        Calendar firingCal= Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8); // At the hour you wanna fire
        firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
        firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second

        Date currentDates = currentCal.getTime();


        if(currentDates.before(firingCal.getTime())){
            //do simething
            // the session still on
        }else{
            // If the current date is after the firingCal.getTime, then sesion destroy
        }

    }
```

On code above i try to destroy the session every 8.00 in the morning.
but the code above doesn't gave what i looking for.

My Question, how to create a session and destroy it in a specific time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you need an action (let, suppose it will be removeSession()) that will perform at every 8 am in morning. Please use `AlarmManger` and `BroadcastReceiver` to do the same. You can use this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.